# select a column twice with two conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table with one column and in it two variables: 'M' and 'F'.
I need to create a table with two columns - 1 with the count of 'F' and the other with the count of 'M' in the same row.
Ideally, I would like to select the count of this column twice, each time with a different condition.
any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing would be to use conditional sum to get the male and female count something as

```
select 
sum(val='M') as male_count,
sum(val='F') as female_count
from test
```

[**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85eb4/1)

Comment: thanks. don't know why but the result was negative... numbers were correct though.... :)

Comment: Could you add some sample data to in the sqlfiddle so that I can check.

Answer (score 0):

use 2 sub queries to select each count and return the counts as 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

Using vp_arth's fiddle

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.val) as MCount, COUNT(t2.val) as FCount
FROM test t1
, test t2
WHERE t1.val = 'M'
AND t2.val = 'F'
```

although I doubt the problem's as simple as you've presented it :)

Comment: it's correct but too expensive, if all, that you need - get Male/Female counts.

Comment: The question states that the OP needs to get two columns

Comment: also `question states that OP needs to create a table` ;), where `create table` clause in your answer?

Comment: It is that simple :)
this is my first time using sql. thanks.